# How to find all test methods (coded UI) dynamically?

Tags: unit-testing, attributes, coded-ui-tests, system.reflection, test-project

I have several test projects written in C#. I need to create a new application (can be a console or WPF application) which needs to refer to the test projects and found out all test methods names dynamically.

So far I was able to find out all methods and properties names in all test projects, but I'm not able to filter out only the test methods names. I was hopping to be able to filter out the test methods by using TestMethodAttribute, because all test methods have [TestMethod] attribute. However it doesn't do the job correctly. Here is an extraction of the code

```
        MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(CodedUITest2).GetMethods();
        Array.Sort(methodInfos, 
                   delegate(MethodInfo methodInfo1, MethodInfo methodInfo2)
                    {return methodInfo1.Name.CompareTo(methodInfo2.Name);});

        foreach (MethodInfo mi in methodInfos)
        {
            object[] al = mi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethodAttribute), false);

            if (al != null)
                Console.WriteLine(mi.Name);

        }
```

The output of the program is
CodedUITestMethod3
Equals
get_TestContext
GetHashCode
GetType
set_TestContext
ToString

So if I delete the following statements, the result is the same.

object[] al =           mi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethodAttribute), false);
if (al != null)

So my question is after finding all methods names, how it is possible to filter the result and get only test method, in this example, it should print only "CodedUITestMethod3"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works on my box,

```
Type type = typeof(CodedUITest2);
IEnumerable<MethodInfo> testMethods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Where(m => m.IsDefined(typeof(TestMethodAttribute)));
```

Answer (score 0):

On the MSDN site I found reference to the following part of VSTest.Console.exe Command-Line Options. Maybe this would help?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx

/ListTests:[ file name ]
Lists discovered tests from the given test container.